# Groupby the list according to category

Tags: python, list, split, group-by, categories

my code gives me output as a list

```
def extractKeywords():
    <code> 
    return list

list = []
data = extractKeywords()
for x in range(0,5):
    get = data[0][x]
    list.append(get)
print list12
```

Output list is

```
['LION', 'tv', 'TIGER', 'keyboard', 'cd-writer','ELEPHANT']
```

How can i categorize this list into two groups like ( Expected output)

```
Animals = ['LION', 'TIGER', 'ELEPHANT']
Electronics = ['tv', 'keyboard', 'cd-writer']
```

All animals are in `Capital letter` and Electronics are in `small letters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = ['LION', 'tv', 'TIGER', 'keyboard', 'cd-writer','ELEPHANT']
[word for word in mylist if word==word.lower()]
```

Comment: Won't this only return the lower case list. The upper case is essentially thrown away.

Comment: If it solves your problem then please accept as an answer. :)

Comment: @RMcG: Just showing the path, Mr.Calm would be smart enough to pick up the rest.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I retract my comment :D

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses itertools.groupby to avoid traversing the list twice.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = ['LION', 'tv', 'TIGER', 'keyboard', 'cd-writer','ELEPHANT']
>>> # upper case letters have lower `ord` values than lower case letters
>>> sort_by_case = sorted(data, key=lambda word: ord(word[0]))
>>> sort_by_case
['ELEPHANT', 'LION', 'TIGER', 'cd-writer', 'keyboard', 'tv']
>>> # group the words according to whether their first letter is upper case or not
>>> group_by_case = groupby(sort_by_case, lambda word: word[0].isupper())
>>> # use tuple unpacking to assign the two groups to appropriate variables
>>> upper_case, lower_case = [list(g) for (k, g) in group_by_case]
>>> upper_case
['ELEPHANT', 'LION', 'TIGER']
>>> lower_case
['cd-writer', 'keyboard', 'tv']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>>
>>> def splitOnCondition(lst, condition):
...   l1, l2 = tee((condition(i), i) for  i in lst)
...   return [i for c, i in l1 if c], [i for c, i in l2 if not c]
...
>>> splitOnCondition(['LION', 'tv', 'TIGER', 'keyboard',
...    'cd-writer','ELEPHANT'], lambda x: x==x.lower())
(['tv', 'keyboard', 'cd-writer'], ['LION', 'TIGER', 'ELEPHANT'])
```